# Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

My emulator is running API 27 with Google play services.  People have suggested doing this:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

They have also suggested setting the emulator to use the 'Host GPU', but that setting is greyed out/disabled on emulators using Google play services.

Can anyone help?  It seems especially ridiculous considering that the Google Maps app itself runs without issue on the emulator.

Comment: If you are on Windows (yes please state OS and version always) perhaps `Added a dropdown to select OpenGL renderer in the Emulator Settings page. If you are having OpenGL driver issues and are on Windows, try out the ANGLE (D3D11) or ANGLE (D3D9) options (requires restart). If you are having OpenGL driver issues but are not on Windows, try out the Swiftshader software renderer (requires restart).` from https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically Nexus 5x and Nexus 5 force to use automatic with Emulated performance for graphics, because of which google maps does not work on emulator. You should try with other devices like **Nexus 4** and google maps work with it.
Here is the screen shot of **Nexus 4**:
[image]

Where as in case of **Nexus 5x or Nexus 5** you cannot change Emulated performance graphics setting:
[image]